# How to prove this inequality similar to AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $0 \le n_1 ,n_2 , ... , n_k < a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,..,m$ and $k \ge 1$ and $m \ge 1$.

Prove that the following inequality holds:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^m\left(a_i - \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}n_j\right) \le  \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{m}(a_i-n_j)\right)
$$
I proved it for $k=2$ with induction for $m$.

But for arbitrary $k$? Induction in two variables?

Comment: Is the sum in LHS $\sum_{j=1}^k n_i$? I think $\sum_{j = 1}^k n_j$ would be the case.

Comment: Thank you - I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the given inequality to prove is

$$
\prod_{i=1}^m\left(a_i - \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}n_{\color{red}{j}}\right) \le  \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{m}(a_i-n_j)\right)
$$

Without loss of generality i'll assume $n_1 \le n_2 \le \cdots \le n_k$.

Since $a_i - \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}n_{j} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k (a_i-n_j)$, we can write more general form of given inequality as for $b_{ij} >0$ and $b_{ij} \ge b_{i(j+1)}$

$$ \prod_{i=1}^m \left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k {b_{ij}}\right) \le \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{m}b_{ij}\right)
$$

Given case is obtained if one put $b_{ij} = a_i- n_j$.

Now, for $m=1$, the inequality is true. (LHS and RHS are the same.)

For $m=2$, the inequality is of the form
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k p_j \right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k q_j \right) \le \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k p_j q_j
\end{align*}
which is the [Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality).

Assume that $m = M$ case is true. Then, for $m = 2M$,

\begin{align*} \prod_{i=1}^{2M} \left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k {b_{ij}}\right) & = \prod_{i=1}^{M} \left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k {b_{ij}}\right) \cdot  \prod_{i=1+M}^{2M} \left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k {b_{ij}}\right) \\ 
& \stackrel{*}{\le} \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{M}b_{ij}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left(\prod_{i=M+1}^{2M}b_{ij}\right)\\ 
& \stackrel{**}{\le}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k \left(\prod_{i=1}^{2M}b_{ij}\right)
\end{align*}

($*$ : $m = M$ case. $**$ : $m=2$ case.)

This lead us to the inequality for $m =$ 2 power cases, i.e. $m =2, 4, 8, \cdots$.

Next step is to show $m = M-1$ case under the condition of $m = M$. For this, just let $b_{Mj} = 1$ for all $j = 1, \cdots, k$ for $m = M$ case.

This covers all natural numbers $m$. So we are done.

Comment: Nice proof-Thank You! Your reformulation to a Chebyshev inequality did the trick- a google search led to https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/proof-of-the-generalised-chebyshevs-sum-inequality/ there a proof is sketched